# CodeIgniter encryption library issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption

I've been looking around for this, but no luck.

I use CodeIgniter 3.1.0 and I use the `$config['encryption_key']` for my encryption key.

I encrypt passwords, and at first, when I used `$this->encryption->decrypt($password)` it worked as it should. When I tested and created a new account, I couldn't log in.

After that happened I've tried matching the encrypted value to the value in the database using `$this->db->where('password', $this->encryption->encrypt($password));` - but still no luck.

After having tested the password input with encryption `echo $this->encryption->encrypt($password)` I found that the value change even though it's the same thing I type in.

Any help is greatly appriciated as I've tried all I can think of.

Comment: you should not *encrypt* the passwords, but *hash* them

Comment: Mind the note on top of the [Encryption module documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html): *DO NOT use this or any other encryption library for user password storage! Passwords must be hashed instead, and you should do that via PHP’s own Password Hashing extension.*

Comment: i think each and evrytime encrypted value may changes based on the algorithm.try retrive encrypted password from db and decrypt with codeigniter fn and check equality..
that should work.